# therubyracer fails to build on heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've made a Rails 3.1 PoC application that also uses haml by adapting the examples from the railstutorial.org book and locally everything works fine.
But when I try to push to **heroku**, **[therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer)** fails to build on the server *([full output](http://pastebin.com/FntHNH0J))*:

```
Installing therubyracer (0.8.2) with native extensions /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
```

My [Gemfile](http://pastebin.com/Si9RLVD9) is pretty standard, so I would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand what's going wrong, and maybe give me a hand in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku [no longer requires, but strongly discourages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#therubyracer) using `therubyracer` or `therubyracer-heroku`, as these gems use a very large amount of memory.

If you are using them your next deploy will fail!

You have 2 choices:

1. Add `'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` to the `group :assets` and upgrade your ruby version. Then remove your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install`.
2. Run `assets:precompile` in your local machine and push them to heroku (don't forget to remove therubyracer gems from production);
3. Rails asset pipeline supports the Sass language by default. Instead of `rails-bootstrap` gem (LESS) you can use [`bootstrap-sass-rails`](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails)

Answer (score 4):

These answers are out of date. You can now just use `therubyracer` in both environments so long as you have version '>= 0.11.2'

I should note that I am the author of therubyracer and use it in several production heroku apps both during asset compile time and at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [therubyracer-heroku](https://github.com/aler/therubyracer-heroku).

Just define a pair of groups in your Gemfile to install the correct one where required.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku'
end
```