# Heroku - therubyracer -v '0.11.0beta8' fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, therubyracer

```
Installing therubyracer (0.11.0beta8) with native extensions
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_2c9eqd3g9wxzt/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
       creating Makefile
       make
       compiling locker.cc
       compiling context.cc
       compiling primitive.cc
       compiling v8.cc
       compiling handles.cc
       compiling string.cc
       compiling date.cc
       compiling exception.cc
       compiling heap.cc
       compiling backref.cc
       compiling script.cc
       compiling function.cc
       compiling invocation.cc
       compiling init.cc
       compiling external.cc
       compiling rr.cc
       compiling array.cc
       compiling value.cc
       compiling template.cc
       compiling constraints.cc
       compiling constants.cc
       compiling trycatch.cc
       compiling stack.cc
       compiling accessor.cc
       compiling message.cc
       compiling signature.cc
       compiling object.cc
       compiling gc.cc
       linking shared-object v8/init.so
       /tmp/build_2c9eqd3g9wxzt/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: could not read symbols: No such file or directory
       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
       make: *** [init.so] Error 1
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2c9eqd3g9wxzt/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2c9eqd3g9wxzt/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta8/ext/v8/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0beta8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0beta8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong here? I've been trying to fix this error for a couple of days now and no luck. This is a somewhat detrimental problem because if I try bundling without it, I get an error with Less which is dependent on it for twitter bootstrap. I've tried using previous versions of therubyracer also, but when I do I get the same exact error with a suggestions of "Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0beta8'succeeds before bundling". Any help would be great!

Update:

When I don't include therubyracer in production at all I get this: (heroku logs)

```
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-08-15T02:15:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-08-15T02:15:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-15T02:15:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-15T02:33:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-15T02:33:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 57351`


2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]: **/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/context.rb:74:in `IsEntered': HandleScope::HandleScope: Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place (fatal)**


2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/portal.rb:74:in `open'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/context.rb:74:in `enter'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/object.rb:18:in `block in []='
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/object.rb:17:in `tap'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/object.rb:17:in `[]='
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/lib/v8/context.rb:58:in `[]='
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/loader.rb:12:in `initialize'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:14:in `new'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:14:in `<module:Less>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-86cffd500849/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-08-15T02:33:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:33:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-15T02:33:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-15T02:37:06+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-08-15T02:37:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by joshua.chestang@gmail.com
2012-08-15T02:37:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5bad9a2 by joshua.chestang@gmail.com
2012-08-15T02:37:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-15T02:37:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-15T02:37:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 36867`





 **2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]: [WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.**
    2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- twitter/bootstrap/rails (LoadError)**
    2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'


2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.rc.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-08-15T02:38:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-08-15T02:38:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-15T02:38:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem  'rails', '3.2.8'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end


gem "heroku"

gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'


gem 'json', '~> 1.6.5'

gem "multi_json", "~> 1.3.6"

#attachment management
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

#ativity feed
gem 'public_activity', :git => "git://github.com/pokonski/public_activity.git"

gem 'jquery-rails'

#nested-album-form
gem 'nested_form', :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'

#creates pattern for widget to send form data in json back to server
gem "js_message"

gem 'kaminari'

#gem 'will_paginate'


#user authentication
gem 'devise'

#notification - basic
gem 'unread'

#id3 tag reader for songs
#gem "taglib-ruby", '~> 0.5.1'

#admin interface
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'

#gravatar images for users with no profile picture
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'

#amazon s3 for song storage
gem 'aws-sdk'

#authentication for twitter
gem 'omniauth-twitter'

#pretty urls
gem 'friendly_id'

gem 'tire'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'nifty-generators'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'watchr'
end

#?
gem 'progress_bar'

#web intents - twitter
gem 'tweet-button'



#like buttons
gem 'facebook_share'

#rails paypal interfacing
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'

#gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'country_select'

# gem 'tiny_tds'
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
# gem 'ruby-odbc'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'debugger'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'minitest'
end
gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try this one? https://github.com/aler/therubyracer-heroku

see [therubyracer fails to build on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259130/therubyracer-fails-to-build-on-heroku)

---

just looked on heroku docs - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

> therubyracer
>
> If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku,
>   these gems are no longer required and strongly discouraged as these
>   gems use a very large amount of memory.

what happens if you do not include therubyracer in your production deploy?

Comment: I get three errors. One says I need to install therubyracer to use Less. I updated my questions and added my heroku logs file. The starred lines are the relevant errors I believe.

Comment: I would add your Gemfile to the post also - might want to consider pre-compiling your assets, check them into git and push that way?

Comment: might want to try heroku google groups or create a support ticket - worst case situation, compile your assets locally and push them to heroku precompiled

Comment: Heroku discorages the use of therubyracer and therubyracer-heroku gems

Answer (score 0):

However heroku discouraged the use of therubyracer gems it's hard to remove this from existing projects without compromise the application.

So there is a solutions ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658793/cant-install-therubyracer-error)).

Add 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby to the group :assets and upgrade your ruby version. Then remove your Gemfile.lock and run bundle install.

Example:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby 
end

gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```